# Responsive website into app or Hybrid mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

So after too many searches I decided to ask this question.
First of all I'm building a mobile app using angularjs in my website (Online) not localhost. The app is a kind of a CRM based (CRUD mostly).
I have the cordova mobile application ready. I have a few questions here.

1. Is it acceptable, if I use the website URL directly in the inappbrowser URL (Like an iframe)?
2. Or. Should I need to put the angularjs files inside the www directory of the cordova app and access the server functions via API?

Which way is preferable? Why? 
Will there be any performance differences?
If the No.1 is not a best practice, what is the major drawback on using the inappbrowser?

Answer (score -1):

You can build [Hosted Web App in an Apache Cordova](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017):

> For this scenario, you use a thin Cordova client (think of it as a web
>   browser embedded in a native app) that automatically redirects to your
>   Web site.

See also: [Wrapping an existing web application in Cordova](https://medium.com/code-divoire/going-mobile-wrapping-an-existing-web-application-in-cordova-phonegap-106d8b60bb9a).

Other option: [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_applications):

> Progressive web applications (PWAs) are web applications that load
>   like regular web pages or websites but can offer the user
>   functionality such as working offline, push notifications, and device
>   hardware access traditionally available only to native applications.
>   PWAs combine the flexibility of the web with the experience of a
>   native application.

Comment: I know all the above mentioned solutions. I wanted to know which is better. 
Wrapping the angularjs contents from server via  an inappbrowser or placing the angularjs contents directly in the cordova?